# Accessing Membership Provider through code without configuration

Tags: membership-provider

I am working on a generic solution (for both SP2010 and SP2013) for any kind of farm. I need to access the Membership APIs in my code from a Console App / Windows Service. Using the SPSite object (then SPWebApplication and IisSettings), I am able to get the Membership and Role Provider names in my code dynamically, without hardcoding them. Now to get the MembershipProvider instance, I use the Membership.Providers[mpName]. But this code doesn't work, unless the appropriate entries are made into the application config file. I cannot make these entries, because my code has to work for different end customers of my customer and hence I want to drive this through code. Of course, I can take the connection string as input, but I want to control everything else through code?

To put it in simple terms, is there a way to get the MembershipProvider instance without configuration elements, but only through code? Please note that I am not talking about removing the config entries from the STS Web.config or SP Web.config. I am only talking about removing these entries from my custom application config and controlling them through my application code.

Can anyone please help?